# SQL Query ( retrieve the value from two different tables, then compare and show the largest value)

Tags: sql

I am stuck with two SQL queries. if someone could me help to understand how to solve it.

1) For all cases where the same reviewer rated the same movie twice and gave it a higher rating the second time, return the reviewer's name and the title of the movie.

2)For each movie that has at least one rating, find the highest number of stars that movie received. Return the movie title and number of stars. Sort by movie title. 
[image: Sample dataset]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vHA8NMTJPZyTgbMA3zPdyX4kKcRipwLVdS4yzYXmLmw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what have you tried so far? could you add data sample es text?

Comment: I am stuck at comparing the ratings( higher rating at a second time for the same movie)

Comment: ok, I am doing that.

Comment: @Horaciux. I have uploaded the data into the spreadsheet and attached the link

Comment: I never used it before, so had no idea about it. Thanks

Comment: Please always show your attempt with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firt part looks like this

```
select m.title, rv.name from Movie m inner join (
select rid,mid  from rating
group by rid,mid
having max(stars)-min(stars)>0) r on m.mid=r.mid
inner join Review rv on rv.rID = r.rID
```

Second part as this:

```
select m.title, max(r.stars) from movie m 
inner join Rating  r on m.mID = r.mID
group by m.title
order by m.title
```